# Accessing SQL server via connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to access a specific sql server and table from my program. I haven't worked with SQL using C# neither for reading not for writing actions.

So how should I try to access a server with these specifications using string connections? I have already tried a few things and I couldn't succeed, and i tried to search this problem, both on google and stackoverflow, but this didn't help either:

```
username = sa ;        
password(example) = 13579 ;
server name = RD-ASGARI-DEL\SQLEXPRESS ;
instance name = SQLEXPRESS ;
computer name = RD-ASGARI-DEL ;
server = ??? how to obtain the server's address ?
database = RD-ASGARI-DEL\SQLEXPRESS : Database \ AIMS \ dbo.t_trend (a table)
```

Comment: Using Visual Studio, create new "SQL Server Database project" and wizard should fill-in all params. for you. And BTW, you have tags for SQL Server 2008 and MySQL, I guess it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Server is the computer on which the SQL server is running (in your case the computer name or ip adress.. )

More information about connectionstrings-> [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)